# How to retrieve exact html element from Zend\Dom\Query object

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-dom-query

I want to use Zend\Dom to get all html elements in a div , but it just extracts the it's text and strips html tags

HTML :

```
<div class="test">
<div id="div1">Text1</div>
<div id="div2">Text2</div>
</div>
```

I want to get this :

```
<div id="div1">Text1</div>
<div id="div2">Text2</div>
```

but Zend\Dom returns this :

```
Text1
Text2
```

This is the code :

```
$dom = new Query($html);
$results = $dom->execute('.test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have html value of results like this :

```
foreach ($results as $result)
{
  $results->getDocument()->saveHTML($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each method in the Zend/Dom class, returns Zend/Dom/NodeList Object .

You should use getDocument Function to get the complete DOM .

```
use Zend\Dom\Query;
$dom = new Query($html);
$results = $dom->execute('.test');
echo $results->getDocument();
```

**Reference : -**

[Zend/Dom/NodeList Documentation of Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.dom.query.html#zend-dom-nodelist)